# Set dynamic class depending of parameter received

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm new using Vuejs and I have a component that I want to set `height` value only if I send a parameter in props

So, my class is something like this:

```
 <input
            tag="section"
            class="h-full"
          >
```

As you can see I use h-full class (tailwind framework) but I want to remove it if prop comes true, so I create a new prop:

```
props: {
 adjustHeightToContent: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  },
```

I want to know how can I set that CSS class to dynamic depending of parameter value

Component usage:

```
<BaseInput v-if="isModalShown"> </BaseInput>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use this:

`:class="adjustHeightToContent ? 'h-auto' : 'h-full'"`

Comment: Awesome,it works!. Thanks